# Limit of a sequence of integral of a rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration

Compute the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+x+1}%
\operatorname*{dx}.
$$

It is about a $\infty\cdot0$ indeterminate. Denote the expression below the
limit with $a_{n}$. I just noted that if
$$
0\leq x\leq1\Rightarrow0\leq x^{n}\leq1
\quad
\text{and}%
\quad
1\leq x^{n}+x+1\leq3;
$$
hence
$$
\frac{1}{3}\leq\frac{1}{x^{n}+x+1}\leq1\quad
\text{or}
\quad
\frac{x^{n}}{3}\leq\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+x+1}\leq x^{n};
$$
then I integrated the above inequality to get that%
$$
\forall n\in
\mathbb{N}
:\frac{1}{3n+3}\leq\frac{a_{n}}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
So $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}=0$. It is possible now to
compute the limit of $\left(  a_{n}\right)  $ from the previous limit? Any
other way to compute the limit? Thank you.

Comment: I think the lower bound $2\le x^n+x+1$ should actually be $1\le x^n+x+1$.

Comment: I modified the mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

The change of variables $y=x^n$ removes the external factor of $n$, putting all the dependence inside the integral:
$$
n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}+x+1} \,dx = n \int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{y+y^{1/n}+1} \tfrac1ny^{1/n-1} dy = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{y^{2-1/n}+y+y^{1-1/n}} \,dy.
$$
The integrand is an increasing function of $n$, so by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/monotone-convergence-theorem),
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{y^{2-1/n}+y+y^{1-1/n}} \,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{y^2+y+y^1} \,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y+2} \,dy = \log\frac32.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^n+x+1}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\left(1-\frac{x+1}{x^n+x+1}\right)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1-\int_0^1\frac{x+1}{x^n+x+1}dx\right)$$
now by redefining $n$ we can get:
$$L=\lim_{n\to 0^+}\frac{1-\int_0^1\frac{x+1}{x^{1/n}+x+1}dx}{n}$$
And now you have a $\frac 00$ situation

Comment: Why you redefine $n$? It is possible to continue this idea in order to obtain the answer without using the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: That is just my preferred way of solving it, you dont have to do it that way